# My pages are going to "Crawled - currently not indexed

Tags: seo

My pages are being unindexed and going to "Crawled - currently not indexed" list while they haven't changed. How can I analyze the issue and what could be the reason?
For example this page:
https://empireexterminatorsnyc.com/pomonok-exterminator/

Can you please give a recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes. I had same situations with my 3-4 blog posts. Just try request indexing in GSC and wait for a 1-2 weeks and also create some backlinks of that page on Medium, Reddit, and Tumbler (On HIGH DA Sites).

If its still not indexing then there might be some issues like content quality, mobile friendliness, canonicalization, etc and check for technical errors too.